# How to run this method in Java?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to run this code that returns the maximum value in the given array. I'm brand new to Java so I would greatly appreciate any debugging tips.

```
public class maxVal {


public static int max(int[] m) {
    int maxSoFar=m[0],i;

    for (i=1; i<m.length;i++) { 

        if (m[i]>maxSoFar)
            maxSoFar=m[i];
            
    }        
    return maxSoFar;
        

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] numbers = new int[]{9, 2, 15, 2, 22, 10, 6};  
   max(numbers); 
}
```

}

Comment: The `max` method returns a value so you may want to print it out.

Comment: you are actually running it, you are just ignoring the returned value

Comment: so I should print out the maxSoFar value rather than returning it? or both?

Comment: no, you should print the value you just returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to see the answer in the console?

When you run `max` method it will return the maximum value in the given array. so to see it in the console you have to print it using `System.out.println()`. or you can also assign it to another variable to use it in somewhere else.

Your code is actually working but you ignore the return value by `max` method.

here is your code with `System.out.println()` to print the maximum value

```java
public class maxVal {


 public static int max(int[] m) {
     int maxSoFar=m[0],I;

     for (i=1; i<m.length;i++) { 

         if (m[i]>maxSoFar)
             maxSoFar=m[I];
             
     }        
     return maxSoFar;
       
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[]{9, 2, 15, 2, 22, 10, 6};  
    
    int maxVal = max(numbers); 
    System.out.println(maxVal);

 }

}
```

Comment: I didn't change the code. :). just add the sout

Comment: my bad, still waking up, I missed the main signature for the other method's :)